# How to ensure the same speed of hard disks among cluster machines?

Tags: hard-disk

I run experiments on cluster machines. Each machine has the exactly same hardware & software configurations.

The runtime of the experiments depends on the sequential read speed of HDD (100% disk io bound jobs).

I found that

1. even though each machine has the same bytes of data, their runtime varies a lot (like 1.3 ~ 1.8 times between the fastest and the slowest).
2. for each run with the different data file, the slowest and fastest machines change. But for the same data file, the results are repeatable.
3. when I perform the same experiments with SSD, the problems are all gone. Most of the machines terminate almost at the same time.

I conducted experiments that just reads the data files stored in the disks of the machines (using 'fio' disk benchmark tool). The results are the same.

My theory is that when the data file is stored in hard disks in each machine, they are stored in the different disk sectors. The outter part of the disk cylinders can have the higher sequential scan speed than the inner part of them. (http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/hard-disk.html, http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/geom/tracksZBR-c.html)

Is there any way to adjust the different disk read speeds, so that I can conduct the experiments with the uniform disk speeds?

Comment: What are the rotational (turns/second, maybe: 7200RPM) speeds of each machine disk? The same?

Comment: @Arrow Each machine has 4 disks of 5400 RPM. The four HDDs are organized as RAID-0

Comment: How big are the files to be processed? kiloBytes MegaBytes GigaBytes?

Comment: @Arrow the file size varies from 10 GB to 100 GB (per file in each machine)

Comment: Then, the sustained **average** read speed of files should be pretty similar for all systems. If the file were small (~kbytes), the read speed could vary with the distribution of sectors in the disk. But that should not be an issue for files so big.  I find it amazing that the speed vary on a factor of 1.8 for such big files. Or, maybe, the files are not read sequentially and the read pattern depends on the actual data each file contains?.

Comment: The only thing an SSD has **not** that a rotational disk has is "rotational delay". The need to wait for the disk to turn to read the next sector. The SSD have a read delay close to zero and it does not depend on the number (position) of next sector. But, even in a rotating disk, if the files were sequentially written (ordered) and are sequentially read, what matters is the average read speed. With the information given it is not possible to give an educated guess.